# QLineEdit: show new text before processing textEdited signal

Tags: pyqt5, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit and a slot that processes the textEdited signal.

I don't want to validate the text, just use it to filter a list of names (different widget) with the ones matching the text in the QLineEdit.

I have found that the text shown in the QLineEdit is only updated after the signal is processed, and the question is: can I make the new text show in the QLineEdit first and then process the signal?

Now I have:

```
1. let's say user presses 'A' key in the QLineEdit
2. textEdited signal is emitted (but QLineEdit is not visually updated yet)
3. signal is processed in my slot (filtering a QListWidget)
4. QLineEdit is updated, showing the effect of pressing the key 'A'
```

If step 3 takes a long time there is too much delay between the key is pressed and it's shown in the QLineEdit, so I want:

```
1. let's say user presses 'A' key in the QLineEdit
2. textEdited signal is emitted (but QLineEdit is not updated yet)
3. signal is processed in my slot (filtering a QListWidget)
   i) update the QLineEdit object to reflect the pressed key 'A'
   ii) filter the QListWidget
```

How can I do that? I need something like a QLineEdit.refresh() method? As I said I don't need to validate de text, I just want to use it to filter the content of a QListWidget, so I want everything the user edit to be shown as fast as possible.

EDIT: I've found that QCoreApplication.processEvents() does the work, but it affects the process of the signal, and some pressed keys don't trigger the signal, although I don't understand why. It seems that if the user say edits the QLineEdit pressing two keys "too fast" then the call to processEvents() in my slot (while processing the first key) processes the second key, so the second key is not processed by my slot. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single-shot timer:

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
self.timer.setInterval(300)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.filterList)
self.edit.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.timer.start())
```

This will keeping re-starting the timer until there's a pause greater than the timer interval, at which point the `timeout` signal will be sent and the slot connected to it will be called.

You may need to adjust the interval to suit the typing speed.

Comment: Thank! Yes, that will solve the QLineEdit refresh problem, as after the Timer starts the GUI gets back the control and it will update the text shown in the QLineEdit.

Comment: Anyway, I think I have now a more complex question... if the filterList process takes a really long time (say a long list o downloading the elements from the internet), all inputs made by the user will be blocked until the filtering is finished... I don't know if I can give back control to the GUI process from time to time or I need to use threads. I'll open a new question as I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @Pablovx. Yes, you will need to start a new question for this. PS: please accept this answer if you found it useful (i.e. click the tick mark).